# IIS and SQL 100% CPU Usage

Tags: iis, sql-server

We have an IIS server running an ASP.net application and SQL Server. Most of the time it runs fine, but recently we have had a couple of instances of severe performance degradation.

The whole site became unresponsive. When I checked the server, the CPU was running at 100% with IIS and SQL the main culprits (e.g. IIS 60%, SQL 40%).

- Restarting the server did not help, as the CPU went back to 100% as soon as the server came back up
- Restarting IIS made no difference
- Restarting SQL made no difference
- It wasn't a DOS attack, as the IIS log didn't show anything unusual. In fact, the amount of activity in the log didn't seem higher than normal.
- It didn't seem to be related to a long-running or unindexed query since the server restart would have fixed that.
- After about 25 - 30 minutes the CPU usage went back to normal by itself.

Have you ever heard of anything like this? Any ideas for a solution or way to prevent it?

Comment: 1) IIS and SQL Server should not be installed on the same machine, as they have conflicting memory footprint. 2) When a site is unresponsive, dump analysis or a performance profiler should tell what's the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your input Lex. Memory was not an issue, it was only using about 35% of total system memory. I will try a dump and see if there is any useful information in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue on a core banking Web application. The problem was that sometimes some of the sessions remained locked into the ASPState database, resulting in hundreds of calls per second to dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive3 for each of the locked sessions.

The CPU on the IIS server would eventually go up with the number of locked sessions. A temporary solution was to recycle the application pool.

Going further and enabling the Tracing on the IIS server(s) and then analyzing the traces you can notice that whenever there was a problem (i.e. network connectivity problem that caused a 500 Internal server error) in the EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER module, the next module which is RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE (and should unlock the session) was not be executed. Thus the session remained locked.

It turned up to be a bug from IIS and we fixed it by changing the value of the uploadReadAheadSize to 0 in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="0" />
</system.webServer>
```

The UploadReadAheadSize property establishes the number of bytes a Web server will read into a buffer and pass to an ISAPI extension. This occurs once per client request.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for the detailed information. I've added uploadReadAheadSize and will see if it makes a difference. I'm going to try tracing IIS and checking out executing queries if it happens again.

Comment: Perfect. I hope the trace helps you identify the issue and I hope the uploadReadAheadSize mitigates or solve the issue..